# Enforce Apparmor on Chromium-based Browsers

Tags: chromium, browser, apparmor

By default, we have this entry in apparmor's enforce mode:

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//browser_java
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//browser_openjdk
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser//sanitized_helper
```

Is apparmor enforced on any Chromium-based browser, like Google Chrome and Vivaldi, or is it just for Chromium only? I can't see a profile for Vivaldi, by the way.

Thanks,

Comment: Does anyone have any insights on this? Thanks.